# How to get a success message after form submission in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, codeigniter

I am doing a form in codeigniter . This is my code:

```html
<?php echo form_open_multipart(''); ?>
<div class="input-group">
    <input maxlength="30" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" required>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <select onchange="getcountrycode(this)" name="country" placeholder="Country" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="">Select Country</option>
        <option value="+971" class="form-control">UAE</option>
        <option value="+968" class="form-control">OMAN</option>
        <option value="+974" class="form-control">QATAR</option>
        <option value="+91" class="form-control">IND</option>
        <option value="+966" class="form-control">KSA</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="input-group" style="display: flex;">
    <input style="width: 27%;text-align: left;padding: 15px;border-right: 0px;" type="tel" id="code" name="code"
        placeholder="*Code" class="form-control" readonly>
    <input style="width: 63%;" type="tel" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile No" class="form-control" required>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <select name="myselect" placeholder="Type" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="">Select Type</option>
        <option value="Product" class="form-control">Product</option>
        <option value="Order" class="form-control">Order</option>
        <option value="Complaint" class="form-control">Complaint</option>
        <option value="Return" class="form-control">Return</option>
        <option value="Refund" class="form-control">Refund</option>
        <option value="Other" class="form-control">Other</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <textarea maxlength="200" name="message" placeholder="Message" class="form-control" required></textarea>
</div>
<center><button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">Submit</button></center>
<br>
</form>
```

I want a success message to pop up after the form is submitted with all the required fields. Can someone please help me ?

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: use flash session for that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide what you have tried so far and potential error codes, so that people can really help you and not code for you. If you need help on How To Ask your question [this is the guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter after insert success message show in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254596/codeigniter-after-insert-success-message-show-in-view)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Controller file

Success Message :

```
$this->session->set_flashdata("success","New User Register Successfull..!");
redirect("user","refresh");
```

Error Message

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('error','Rong User Details');
redirect("user","refresh");
```

View file

```
<?php 
    if ($this->session->flashdata('success')) { ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php 
     ?>
    <?php 
    if ($this->session->flashdata('error')) { ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?>
        </div> 
    <?php 
?>
```